# "Theoretische Informatik" oder "theoretische Informatik"

Tags: spelling, capitalization

Schreibt man das T in "Theoretische Informatik" groß oder klein? Eigentlich würde ich, da "theoretisch" ein Adjektiv ist, es eher kleinschreiben. Aber ich habe es bisher ausschließlich großgeschrieben gesehen.

(Das Gleiche gilt für "Praktische Informatik", "Angewandte Informatik", "Technische Informatik".)

Answer (score 18):

(Ich habe statt *theoretischer* aus Versehen *technische* Informatik gelesen. Die folgende Beispiele gelten natürlich gleichermaßen.)

Wenn das Fachgebiet gemeint ist, muss das Adjektiv klein geschrieben werden:

> Die technische Informatik ist eine Querschnittsdisziplin aus Elektrotechnik und Informatik.

Der einzige denkbare Fall für eine Großschreibung ist die Interpretation von `Technische Informatik` als Eigenname. Das könnte z. B. zutreffen, wenn eine bestimmte Vorlesung gemeint ist:

> Die Veranstaltung Technische Informatik findet nur im Sommersemester statt.

Oder eine Institution:

> Mit dem Wechsel der Institutsleitung wurde das Institut für Kommunikations- und Rechnernetze in Institut für Technische Informatik umbenannt.

Während beim Institutsnamen eindeutig ein Eigenname vorliegt, so ist der Fall bei der Veranstaltung nicht ganz so klar. Die [Definition von Eigenname auf canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Eigenname&language=0&project=1) besagt, dass der Eigenname als "eindeutiger Bezeichner dient". Während im Vorlesungsverzeichnis einer bestimmten Uni eindeutig ist, um welche Vorlesung es sich handelt (was die Großschreibung rechtfertigt) trifft das in anderem Kontext nicht unbedingt zu. So würde ich in folgendem Satz die Kleinschreibung verwenden:

> Die technische Informatik ist an vielen Hochschulen inzwischen fester Bestandteil des Elektrotechnik-Studiums.

Der entsprechende [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenname#Kategorien_von_Eigennamen) führt keine Kategorie, die eine Einordnung von Veranstaltungsbezeichnungen in Eigennamen rechtfertigen würde. Auf der deutschen [Wiktionary-Seite](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Deutsch/Gro%C3%9F-_und_Kleinschreibung_von_Adjektiven) hingegen werden Veranstaltungen als mögliche Träger von Eigennamen genannt. In den amtlichen Regeln zur deutschen Rechtschreibung vom 1.12.1995 ist der Eigenname in §60 definiert, dort findet sich die Veranstaltung wiederum nicht als Kategorie. Allerdings steht dort in §63:

> In substantivischen Wortgruppen, die zu festen Verbindungen geworden, aber keine Eigennamen sind, schreibt man Adjektive klein.

Als Beispiel ist unter anderem *künstliche Intelligenz* aufgeführt. Meiner Auffassung nach fällt *technische Informatik* ebenfalls unter diese Regelung.

Comment: Die Technische Informatik - als Vorlesung - ist ein eindeutiger Bezeichner, weil sowohl in Stuttgart als auch in Berlin sowie auch sonst irgendwo im Kern dieselben Inhalte gelehrt werden sollten. Wenn Institute oder Lehrstühle gemeinst sind, muss es natürlich auch groß geschrieben werden.

Comment: @chaero Beim Veranstaltungsnamen muss man wohl genauer differenzieren. Der Hinweis mit dem Institutsnamen ist natürlich richtig. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend geändert.

Comment: Ich sehe einen semantischen Unterschied zwischen "theoretischer Informatik" (das ist nur theoretisch, aber nicht praktisch Informatik) und "Theoretischer Informatik" (das ist das Fachgebiet).

Comment: "Während im Vorlesungsverzeichnis einer bestimmten Uni eindeutig ist, um welche Vorlesung es sich handelt (was die Großschreibung rechtfertigt) trifft das in anderem Kontext nicht unbedingt zu." - all das gilt aber genauso für den Institutsnamen. Überhaupt: "Während beim Institutsnamen eindeutig ein Eigenname vorliegt" - so eindeutig finde ich das nicht, denn auch Institutsnamen sind zunächst einmal beschreibend.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich würde Veranstaltung und Institut in dieser Frage ja gar nicht unterschiedlich behandeln: beide müssen meiner Meinung nach großgeschrieben werden, wenn eben ein ganz bestimmtes Institut oder eine bestimmte Vorlesung gemeint ist. Das Fachgebiet an sich würde ich nicht großschreiben.

Comment: @Deve: Sehe ich nicht so. Einerseits besagt [Rechtschreibregel 150 des Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/namen): "Nicht am Anfang des Namens stehende Adjektive werden gelegentlich auch kleingeschrieben" Andererseits sehe ich sowohl Veranstaltungs- als auch Institutsname gar nicht eindeutig als Eigennamen an, auch wenn die Identifikation *eine* ihrer Funktionen ist - der inhaltlich beschreibende Charakter steht bei diesen Bezeichnungen eben auch sehr im Vordergrund. Somit könnte es sich gleichermaßen um eine (eindeutige) inhaltliche Kurzbeschreibung handeln.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich habe in meiner Antwort bereits beschrieben, dass es keine eindeutigen Regeln zu diesem Fall gibt. Diejenige, die du jetzt zitierst, ist es auch nicht. Also bezieht sich dein Einwand jetzt darauf, dass ich in meinem Kommentar "müssen" verwendet habe?

Comment: @Deve: Genau, ich widerspreche allein dem "müssen".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Einverstanden, ich nehme es zurück.

Comment: Sowie englischsprachige (Englisch-sprachige?) Hebräer *G-d* als Eigenname auffassen, bzw. JHWH schrei-ben, würde ich konsequent Majuskeln wählen, "THEORETISCHE INFORMATIK". DAS IST ÜBRIGENS EIN PLEONASMUS. ups, die Umstelltaste klemmt.

Answer (score 18):

Ich würde in diesem Fall die Duden-[Rechtschreibregel 89](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K89) in Anspruch nehmen. Unter Punkt 3 heißt es

> Adjektive, die mit dem folgenden Substantiv einen idiomatisierten
> Gesamtbegriff bilden, können großgeschrieben werden

Bei der Häufigkeit, mit der *Theoretische Informatik* in einem bestimmten Kontext mit einer spezifischen Bedeutung verwendet wird, kann man - denke ich - von einem "idiomatisierten Gesamtbegriff" ausgehen. Dennoch - aus der selben Quelle:

> die Kleinschreibung der Adjektive ist jedoch auch hier der Regelfall

Es geht also beides.

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied wird klarer mit einem Beispiel:

> K. studierte lieber die technische Informatik als die schöngeistige Musik.

Hier ist es ein Adjektiv. Das Spezialgebiet *Technische Informatik* wäre hier nicht gemeint, sondern Informatik im Ganzen als etwas Technisches klassifiziert. Dagegen kann man zum Beispiel brotlose Kunst studieren aber nicht *Brotlose Kunst*.

Ein Spezialfach *praktische Informatik* gibt es meines Wissens nicht.

Literatur ist nicht immer französisch, daher sollte klar sein, dass *Französische Literatur* ein Fach ist, keine Beschreibung von Literatur generell als etwas französischem, aber auf die Empfehlung "Lies mal Bacon!" kann man antworten: "Ich interessiere mich nur für französische Literatur" (nicht für englische).

> Ich interessiere mich nur für Französische Literatur

würde dagegen bedeuten, man interessiert sich nicht für Fußball, Politik oder das andere Geschlecht.

Bei theoretischer Informatik oder Theoretischer Informatik ist das allerdings nicht so klar, denn Informatik ist generell etwas, das man als theoretisch bezeichnen kann.

Answer (score 0):

Es hängt eindeutig davon ab, was mit dem Wort ausgedrückt werden soll. Wenn sich „theoretisch“ tatsächlich darauf bezieht, dass etwas nur im Kopf aber nicht in der Realität existiert; wenn es also ein *eigenständiges* Attribut ist, dann sollte es kleingeschrieben werden.

> Die Turingmaschine ist ein Gegenstand der theoretischen Informatik.

Wenn es um eine Bezeichnung geht, die zwar möglicherweise auf dem ursprünglichen Attribut beruht, aber im Zusammenhang mit dem Substantiv eine eigene Bedeutung bekommt, dann sollte sie großgeschrieben werden.

> Die Disziplin heißt Theoretische Informatik. (und somit auch der Professor für ~/ der Lehrstuhl für ~ / der Hörsaal für ~ / das Lehrbuch über ~)

So könnte man zum Beispiel sagen:

> In der Disziplin Theoretische Informatik geht es um theoretische Informatik, z. B. die Turing-Maschine.

Vergleiche zum Beispiel: *„ohmscher Widerstand“*, aber *„Ohm'sches Gesetz“*. Anderes Resultat aber gleiche Regel.

Comment: Die beiden korrekten Schreibweisen „ohmscher Widerstand“ und „Ohm’scher Widerstand“ ergeben sich aus § 62. Das ist nicht die gleiche Regel wie in den Fällen „theoretische Informatik“ (§ 63) und „Theoretische Informatik“ (§ 64).

Comment: @Loong § 62 erlaubt prinzipiell beide Schreibweisen, ohne zu differenzieren, wann welche angebracht sei. Dies passiert erst in § 64 (oder auch § 63, wenn man so will).

Comment: Das "Ohm'sche Gesetz" vs. "ohmsche Gesetz" ist eine andere Regel. Hier sorgt das Auslassungszeichen für die Grossschreibung.

Comment: @tofro Das ist falsch. Der Apostroph sorgt nicht für die Großschreibung, sondern Großschreibung und Apostroph folgen beide aus derselben Regel.

Comment: "darauf bezieht, dass etwas nur im Kopf aber nicht in der Realität existiert", dass würde die richtige Schreibweise aber abhängig vom philosophischem Standpunkt des *Lesers* machen da nicht jeder die Auffassung vertitt, dass das theoretische nur im Kopf nicht aber in der Realität um uns existiert (diese Formulierung alleine hat schon so viele versteckte Annahmen...). Es darf bezweifelt werden, dass diese Fragestellung auf diese Art und Weise in unsere Grammatik getragen wurde.

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda Natürlich hängt die richtige Schreibweise vom philosophischen Standpunkt ab, denn die unterschiedlichen Schreibweisen drücken unterschiedliche Bedeutungen aus. Nebenbei geht es hier nicht um Grammatik, sondern um Rechtschreibung, für die es feste Regeln gibt.