# Eulersche Zahl - groß oder klein?

Tags: capitalization

Schreibt man das "E" in eulersche Zahl groß oder klein? Wie bspw. [diese Diskussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6154/theoretische-informatik-oder-theoretische-informatik) zeigt, werden solche zusammengesetzten Begriffe oft fälschlicherweise als Namen behandelt und großgeschrieben, obwohl klein richtig wäre (etwa künstliche Intelligenz oder theoretische Informatik). Nun ist Euler ja tatsächlich ein Name, aber

> eulersche Zahl

sieht für mich trotzdem richtiger aus als

> Eulersche Zahl

In der o.a. Diskussion behaupten Toscho und Loong, dass bei

> ohmscher Widerstand

im Prinzip beides geht. Ich konnte die Regeln nicht finden, auf die sich da bezogen wird.

Comment: Verwandte Frage: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5316/1487

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Von Eigennamen abgeleitete Adjektive (und darum handelt es sich hier) werden nach §62 (Regeln des Rechtschreibrats) i.A. *klein* geschrieben.

Von *Personennamen* abgeleitete Adjektive auf "-sch" werden daher generell ebenfalls *klein* geschrieben. Eine Ausnahme gilt, wenn die Endung über ein Auslassungszeichen abgetrennt wird - Dann wird der eigentliche Namensbestandteil, da der Name hier sozusagen "alleine dasteht", *gross* geschrieben.

> die Euler'sche Zahl vs. die eulersche Zahl

In §64 macht man allerdings ein Hintertürchen auf, der für stehende *termini technici* in *Fachsprachen* (für die *eulersche Zahl* sicher diskutierbar) die Gross-/Kleinschreibung der Fachsprache überlässt. Das ist allerdings als *Beobachtung* und nicht als *Regel* formuliert. Ich denke, die Befolgung von §62 folgt daher einer höheren Priorität, zumal manche der in §62 aufgeführten und klein geschriebenen) Begriffe durchaus auch in diese Kategorie fallen können (z.B. *die napoleonischen Kriege* oder *die darwinsche Evolutionstheorie*).

Comment: Aha, das mit den termini technici ist interessant. Ich blättere gerade in einem alten Brockhaus und wundere mich, dass es "mal so und mal so" ist. Das wird dann wohl daran liegen. Wie finde ich denn die Paragraphen, die ihr immer so schön zitiert?

Comment: @lukas.coenig http://www.rechtschreibrat.com unter "Regeln"

Comment: @lukas.coenig Oder [canoo.net](http://canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/index.html)

Comment: Danke, hab ich mir schon alles angeschaut.

Comment: In jedem Mathematiktext, den ich gesehen habe, wird _Eulersche Zahl_ geschrieben. Viele Beispiele findet man hier: http://link.springer.com/search?query=Eulersche+Zahl .

Answer (score 10):

Die in der Frage erwähnte Diskussion bezog sich unter anderem auf die in § 62 des amtlichen Regelwerks festgelegten Regel:

> Kleingeschrieben werden adjektivische Ableitungen von Eigennamen auf -(i)sch, außer wenn die Grundform eines Personennamens durch einen Apostroph verdeutlicht wird, ferner alle adjektivischen Ableitungen mit anderen Suffixen.

(Das amtlichen Regelwerk kann man [hier (pdf)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160624013638/http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf), [hier (pdf)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170828173510/http://www.duden.de:80/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf), oder auch [hier (html)](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/index.html) finden. Es wird gewöhnlich auch in einem Anhang im Duden Band 1 *Die deutsche Rechtschreibung* aufgeführt.)

Ausgewählte Beispiele aus dem amtlichen Regelwerk:

- die darwinsche/Darwin’sche Evolutionstheorie,
- das wackernagelsche/Wackernagel’sche Gesetz,
- die goethischen/goetheschen/Goethe’schen Dramen,
- die bernoullischen/Bernoulli’schen Gleichungen

Ausgewählte Beispiele aus dem Duden:

- ohmscher/Ohm’scher Widerstand
- ohmsches/Ohm’sches Gesetz

Comment: Die Antwort ist ebenfalls gut - ich kann halt nur eine auswählen, und tofro's Antwort enthielt noch ein paar mehr Details. Und war schneller...

Comment: Die Antwort ist wohl richtig, aber logisch ist die Regel nicht. Das Auslassungszeichen ändert ja nicht den Worttyp.

Comment: Hier habe ich ein Video gefunden, das meine Ansicht stützt: http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/apostroph.php , welches m.E. sehr zu Recht die Frage aufwirft, wieso der Apostroph bei Kleinschreibung verschwinden darf, bzw. umgekehrt, wieso er bei Großschreibung stehen sollte. Der Macher bestreitet, dass es stehen sollte und bringt einleuchtende Argumente.

Answer (score 2):

Die anderen Antworten sagen bereits, wie die Regelung heute ist. Aber es ist vermutlich hilfreich zu wissen, dass es vor der Rechtschreibreform anders war, und man deshalb sowohl in älteren Texten, als auch in vielen Texten von Menschen, die die Rechtschreibung vor der Reform gelernt haben, die "Eulersche Zahl" mit großem E und ohne Apostroph finden wird.

Comment: Ist das wirklich so? Ich habe nämlich inzwischen auch noch in einem alten Brockhaus nachgeschlagen (definitiv vor der Reform). Eulersch kam in diesem Sinne nicht vor (also im Satz, wo man sehen kann, ob es groß oder klein ist), aber euklidisch wurde mehrfach klein geschrieben. Ich will nicht ausschließen, dass auch da mal ein Fehler passiert sein kann, aber eine Quelle für die frühere Regelung wäre super!

Comment: @lukas.coenig Die **alte** Duden-Regel 134 lautete: „Von Personennamen abgeleitete Adjektive werden groß geschrieben, wenn sie die persönliche Leistung oder Zugehörigkeit ausdrücken. Diese Adjektive werden klein geschrieben, wenn sie aussagen, daß etwas nach einer Person benannt worden ist oder ihrer Art, ihrem Geist entspricht. (…)“ Zum Beispiel hieß es _Platonische Schriften_ (Schriften Platos) und _das Ohmsche Gesetz_, aber _platonische Liebe_ (nach Plato benannt) und _der ohmsche Widerstand_.

Comment: Aha, ok! Danke für diese Klarstellung, das rückt alles nochmal in ein anderes Licht.

Comment: Dann wäre aber eulersche Zahl immer noch klein... Oder sagen wir, es wäre ein Grenzfall...

Comment: @lukas.coenig: Ich gebe zu, ich habe nie explizit über den Ursprung der eulerschen Zahl nachgeforscht, bin aber immer davon ausgegangen, dass sie tatsächlich von Euler stammt, was hieße, dass sie eine persönliche Leistung Eulers darstellt.

Comment: Mhh... Na gut, kann sein... (Ist nur etwas schräg, weil die Zahl ja schon vorher da war. Die Leistung war höchstens, sie zu finden. Aber ja, wahrscheinlich ist (bzw. war) das so zu interpretieren.)

Comment: @lukas.coenig: Die Bewegung makroskopischer Objekte folgte auch schon der newtonschen Mechanik, bevor Newton sie formulierte. Und dennoch würden die meisten Menschen sie als persönliche Leistung Newtons ansehen, und sie wurde früher definitiv großgeschrieben.

Comment: Oder anders gesagt: Blöde Regel, gut, dass sie weg ist.

Comment: Die alte Regel war viel sinnvoller! Und tatsächlich geht die Eulersche Zahl auf Euler zurück, wie auch die Eulersche Konstante, die Eulersche Polyederformel, Eulersche Graphen und einige Dutzend andere Begriffe.

Comment: @Loong: Ich finde die alte Erklärung nicht gut erläutert (persönliche Leistung). Die Eulersche Zahl ist ein Eigenname der Zahl, während eine eulersche Zahl wie eine loongsche Antwort einfach eine Adjektivbildung ist. In einer fiktiven Biographie über Euler könnte man etwa einen Matheunterricht beschreiben, in dem ein Wert zu berechnen war, und nur die eulersche Zahl war die richtige Lösung, aber die Lösung war nicht die Eulersche Zahl. Mit Groß-/Kleinschreibung ist das ausreichend und konform zu den sonstigen Regeln abgefrühstückt. Wozu es da noch eines Apostrophs bedarf erschließt sich nicht.

Comment: Der Rechtschreibrat liegt hier m.E. einfach falsch. Man schreibt ja auch "Lahms Flanke erreichte Müller" weil der Mann Lahm heißt, nicht "Lahm's Flanke" aber "Brahms' Requiem erreichte die Herzen der Konzertbesucher", weil Brahms von sich aus schon mit einem S endet und der Komponist nicht "Brahm" hieß. Das zweite, weggelassene s wird mit dem Apostroph markiert. Zwar kann man sagen, dass in der Eulerschen Zahl ein I verschwunden ist (Eulerische Zahl), aber das gilt unabhängig davon, ob es adjektisch (klein) oder als Eigenname (groß) geschrieben wird.

Answer (score 0):

Im Gegensatz zu einem Begriff wie "napoleonischer Krieg" gehört der Begriff "eulersche Zahl" zur mathematischen Fachsprache. Zitat aus https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematik:

> Eine Besonderheit der mathematischen Fachsprache besteht in der Bildung von aus Mathematikernamen abgeleiteten Adjektiven wie pythagoreisch, euklidisch, eulersch, abelsch, noethersch und artinsch.

In der Mathematik ist das ein sehr häufig angewandtes Verfahren der Begriffsbildung. Ich möchte hier durch das Hintertürchen in tofros Antwort gehen: Die Groß-/Kleinschreibung bleibt der Fachsprache überlassen.

Während meines Studiums der Mathematik habe ich folgende Theorie zur Wortgenese kennengelernt:

1. Ein neuer Begriff wird von einem Mathematiker unter neutralem Namen eingeführt.
2. Falls der Begriff innerhalb seines mathematischen Fachgebiets Akzeptanz und Verbreitung findet (in der Regel wird das eher bei Begriffsbildungen von Spitzenmathematikern so sein), wird er von Kollegen zu seinen Ehren noch unter Großschreibung mit seinem Namen verknüpft (z.B. "Hausdorff-Raum" oder "Hausdorffscher Raum" nach Felix Hausdorff).
3. Als letzter Schritt erfolgt die Adelung durch Kleinschreibung ("hausdorffscher Raum"). Das bedeutet, dass der Begriff endgültig zum mathematischen Standard gehört und den Übergang zu einem "normalen Adjektiv" geschafft hat.

Answer (score -4):

Am ehesten rate ich dazu, Konstruktionen mit *-sch* zu meiden. Sie sind schnöselig und stehen meist dort, wo ein einfacher Genitiv oder eine Präpositionalphrase passender wäre:

Gut: Goethes Dramen / Dramen von Goethe

Schlecht: Goethe'sche Dramen

Wenn etwas so gefestigt ist wie die Eulersche Zahl, dann schreibt man am besten groß. Es handelt sich um einen Eigennamen wie auch bei der Deutschen Bahn.

Den Apostroph sollte man grundsätzlich meiden (Ausnahmen: Kontraktionen, Genitiv-s), weil er das Schriftbild stört. Hier ist er sowieso falsch, weil ja nichts weggelassen wird.

Oder reden wir deut'sch und fahren mit der Deut'schen Bahn?

---

Die Eulersche Zahl ist ein Eigenname. Denn im Gegensatz zur künstlichen Intelligenz, wo die Intelligenz künstlich ist, ist die Eulersche Zahl nicht eulersch, sondern von Euler entdeckt worden.

Wenn die theoretische Informatik ein Fachbereich ist so wie die Historische Sprachwissenschaft, dann schreibt man auch da groß.

Comment: Der Vergleich mit der Deut'schen Bahn hinkt, weil im Gegensatz zu Euler und Goethe, "Deut" kein Eigenname ist. Und neben Kontraktionen und Genitiv-s gibt es eben noch diesen einen weiteren Anwendungsfall für das Apostroph. Und das Schriftbild wird keineswegs gestört, es wird sogar verdeutlicht.

Comment: Weitaus schnöseliger ist es, wenn jemand sein tolles Deutsch demonstrieren muss, indem er irgendwas mit "Eulers Zahl" zu konstruieren beginnt, obwohl es alle Welt als eulersche Zahl kennt. Gut und schlecht ist immer eine Frage der Perspektive. Wenn sich etwas eingebürgert hat, fällt es immer auf, wenn man es anders macht. Dann nicht schnöselig zu wirken, ist schon eine Kunst.

Comment: @Em1: Und nur Eigennamen haben das Anrecht auf einen Apostroph? Dass der Apostroph das Schriftbild verdeutlicht, ist nicht ganz Communis opinio bei den Typographen.

Answer (score -5):

Da *Eulersche Zahl* ein Eigenname ist, wird beides grossgeschrieben.
Wobei es auch sonst grossgeschrieben würde, da *Euler* ein Name ist und *Zahl* ein Substantiv.

Comment: *eulersch* ist ein **Adjektiv**.

Comment: Da ich es nicht weiß, aber zu tofro's Version tendiere, wäre es schön, wenn hier ein Beleg hinzugefügt werden könnte.

Comment: eulersch ist kein Adjektiv, sondern eine Adjektivierung.
Tatsächlich ist mir jedoch ein Fauxpas unterlaufen, da ich nicht zwischen eulersche und Euler'sche unterschieden habe. Sorry!

Comment: @MichelleH kein Problem - du kannst das leicht beheben, indem du deine Antwort editierst