# Von Namen abgeleitete Adjektive: groß oder klein?

Tags: adjective, capitalization

Schreibt man von Namen abgeleitete Adjektive groß oder klein?

> das *Hegelsche* Werk oder das *hegelsche* Werk?

Comment: Related: [Eulersche Zahl - groß oder klein?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31430/9551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjektive auf der Grundlage von Namen können auf mehrere Weisen gebildet werden, unter anderem:

- mit -esk (vom dem frz. *-esque*), wenn ausgedrückt werden soll, dass etwas nach Art einer Person geschieht (z. B.: kafkaeske Stimmung)
- oder mit -sch, wenn ausgedrückt werden soll, dass etwas von dieser Person stammt (z. B.: das hegelsche Werk).

Für die Bildung gibt es laut [Duden (D 135)](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/namen), was die Groß- und Kleinschreibung anbelangt, zwei Möglichkeiten (sofern nicht andere Regeln greifen, etwa bei Werktiteln):

> 1. Von Personennamen abgeleitete Adjektive werden kleingeschrieben <§ 62>.
> 2. Adjektive auf -sch werden großgeschrieben, wenn die Grundform des Namens mit einem Apostroph verdeutlicht wird.

Es heißt also

> **k**afkaeske Stimmung, nicht aber <strike>**K**afkaeske</strike> Stimmung.

Es kann aber heißen:

> das **h**egelsche Werk oder das **H**egel’sche Werk

Comment: Nur zur Ergaänzung: andere Endungen sind *-istisch* (wie in *marxistisch*, *calvinistisch*), *-ianisch* (wie in *kantianisch*, *cartesianisch*)

Comment: Wahrscheinlich sollte man *-istisch* aber eher als das von dem mit *-ismus* gebildeten Nomen abgeleitete Adjektiv ansehen.